# Simplifying scheduling task programmatically for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking for some project/library/solution for my c++/qt application that may provide programming/scheduling task on Windows. I've read some about Windows Task Schedulers 1.0 and 2.0 API-s, but I really don't enjoy its COM interface. This time I need simplicity and reliability opposite to full functionality.

Attached below could be a model solution, but it works only for .NET. 
http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75/Basic-class-for-using-the-Microsoft-Task-Scheduler) nice wrapper for Task Scheduler 1.0. It will work in all versions of Windows, including Windows 7/server 2008. However, the tasks created using this wrapper will not be visible via Windows 7 control panel. I have enhanced the class and added a support for Task Scheduler 2.0. I can provide an example if interested.